# ReactJS: How to autofocus inputs in a slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application like quiz. Every single slider has one input. I want to autofocus the related input when the user clicks on the `next` button or press on the `enter`.

I tried to achieve it by using `useEffect`. However, it doesn't work.

This is the related function which includes the `next` function of slick and `focus` attribute of inputs:

```
const inputRef = useRef([]);

const handleEnter = (event, index) => {
      if (event.key.toLowerCase() === "enter") {
          sliderRef.current.slickNext(); // The next slider function of the react-slick package
          inputRef.current[index].focus()
      }
}
```

Here are my inputs in `map` function:

```
{data.map((post, index) => (
  <Input 
     id={post.question_uuid} 
     name={post.question_uuid} 
     onKeyDown={e => {handleEnter(e, index)}}
     autoComplete="off
     ref={el => inputRef.current[index] = el}
  />
))}
```

Comment: Are you using `forwardRef()` on the `<Input>` component? (I suppose it's a functional component)

Answer (score 0):

Use useRef for every input and store them on an array with the index that came from your map then after changing every slide you can get the input ref from the array based on the current index and call
array[index].current.focus()